# scope of work and supply list

Tags: word-choice, verbs, grammatical-number

when introducing a list of included / not included items in a scope of work, would you say "in our scope of work are/are not included"...or "in our scope is/is not included"...
consider lists always contain more than two items
when saying "in our price is included" and "in our prices are included" the number of items in the list becomes irrelevant, IMO, but as "scope of work" is always singular it's not clear (to me) which is the correct form

thanks

joe

Comment: The number agreement (*is/are*) depends on the included thing(s), not on "scope of work."

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Dupe of [this (closed) question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224024/when-to-use-is-vs-are).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use "is" vs. "are"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224024/when-to-use-is-vs-are)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a passive "In our scope of work are included x, y, and z", I would propose "Our scope of work includes x, y, and z." Similarly, instead of "In our price list are included x, y, and z", I would use an active "Our price list includes x, y, and z."  In your original constructions, your subject (scope of work or price list) is hopelessly lost.  You have a prepositional phrase (In our scope of work), followed by a verb (is/are included), followed by the subject of the verb (the list of things that are included).  Subject first (Our scope of work), then verb (includes), then object(s) of the verb (x, y, and z) is a more clear construction.